# why updatedb command takes too much time?

Tags: cygwin, locate, updatedb

I have read that to run **locate** command on **CYGWIN** first I need to run the following command.

```
updatedb --localpaths=c:/
```

what this command exactly do as I run this on CYGWIN and it is taking too much time.

Answer (score 7):

This updates the locate database, which will indeed take a long time. It has to traverse every path on the system and then index it appropriately, which requires a lot of work (and a lot of resources).

While it's not really possible to speed up population of the database, you can make it less intrusive by increasing the niceness and io-niceness of `updatedb`. You can do this by using the `nice` and `ionice` utilities, in a manner similar to the following:

```
nice -n 19 ionice -c 3 updatedb --localpaths=c:/
```

Comment: @Elvin If you want to stop it, just send `SIGTERM`: `pkill -x updatedb`, assuming you have pkill, or find its PID and kill it (or if it is running in a terminal you have open, press C-c to send `SIGINT`).

Answer (score 0):

While the statements in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/106453/13187) are true, there may be other issues here.

In my case it took hours as the AV software was scanning every file that `updatedb` was accessing (i.e. almost every file on the disk) and it even caused OneDrive to download a few big files that were not on the disk (files that are in the cloud but not on the local disk get downloaded when they are accessed)

On the same hardware and indexing the same files, but without AV or OneDrive, it took minutes.

It may be a bug in Cygwin's `updatedb` as I don't think it should access to the content of files. Other similar software like `locate32` doesn't cause this.